# Installation Zabbix

Tags: monitoring, snmp

I am trying to install a Zabbix monitoring system on my Ubuntu. But when I try to install it. I get this error:

```
The following have unmet dependencies:
 zabbix-server-mysql : Depends: libsnmp15 (>= 5.4.3~dfsg) but it is no installable
                       Reccomends snmptt but it is not going to be installed
Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I already tried:

```
apt-get update -f
apt-get install snmpd -f
```

but nothing seems to work, anyone has a solution for me?
Thanks

Comment: Were you able to find a solution? I'm also wrestling with this issue...

Comment: No I am sorry, didn't find any solution :s

Comment: I found a solution that may work for you...this issue arises in Ubuntu 13.10, but Zabbix 2.2 is supported in Ubuntu 12.04. If you try installing in a stock Ubuntu 12.04, you will not have this error (I just verified this).

Answer (score 0):

Starting from a stock Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS install, Zabbix can be installed in the following way:

From the [Zabbix 2.2 documentation](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.2/manual/installation/install_from_packages):

```
wget http://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/2.2/ubuntu/pool/main/z/zabbix-release/zabbix-release_2.2-1+precise_all.deb
dpkg -i zabbix-release_2.2-1+precise_all.deb
apt-get update
```

then, to install the server and web frontend:

```
apt-get install zabbix-server-mysql zabbix-frontend-php
```

to install the Zabbix agent only:

```
apt-get install zabbix-agent
```

Answer (score 0):

at first delete zabbix.list

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/zabbix.list
```

and then run commands from in documentation (Answer Y or I when you run dpkg -i .....):

```
# wget http://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/2.2/ubuntu/pool/main/z/zabbix-release/zabbix-release_2.2-1+precise_all.deb
# sudo dpkg -i zabbix-release_2.2-1+precise_all.deb
# sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: If you are going to answer an old question, you might go so far as to [edit] and update the answer with the current version, rather than simply copying a previous answer.